# OpenGL - Print 2D Text in fixed position on the screen in a 3D world

Tags: text, fonts, position, fixed, opengl-3

I am creating a 3D world in OpenGL & C++, with a 3D model moving in 3D world. I have to put on the screen some 2D text: the camera is constantly following the model and I would like the text to appear in a fixed position with respect to the window.
any body can please paste a sample code ? Any tutorial,  link?
Kind regards : Mehrgan

Answer (score 0):

Transform your 3D world position by multiplying it with your projection, view and model matrices. You should obtain the normalized device coordinates of the point, between [-1,1].